# Gradle uploadArchives task unable to read secret key

Tags: gradle, code-signing, gnupg

I have created a gradle project and everything builds fine, but when I try to upload to my Maven repository, I get the following Gradle error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not evaluate onlyIf predicate for task ':library:signArchives'.
> Unable to read secret key from file: C:\Users\ideal\pubring.gpg (it may not be a PGP secret key ring)
```

I followed the instructions [at Sonatype](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/working-with-pgp-signatures.html) to generate the key, then copied it from its generated location to the location listed above. I have also published the public key to MITs key repository. The `gradle.properties` file in my user directory contains the following entries related to the keychain:

```
signing.keyId=MY_KEY_ID
signing.password=MY_KEY_PASSWORD
signing.secretKeyRingFile=C:\\Users\\ideal\\pubring.gpg
```

This is on a Windows platform. I have tried searching for the error message but the only thing which comes up is the source files for the related plugins.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the public key, switch to the secret key, normally named "secring.gpg".
So in your case it should placed in

> C:\Users\ideal\secring.gpg

Answer (score 81):

The `secring.gpg` file has been [removed in GPG 2.1](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring).

However, GPG still can create such a file: `gpg --export-secret-keys -o secring.gpg`

**Pro Tip:** If Gradle's `signing plugin` complains that your key in `signing.keyId=MY_KEY_ID` is too long, you're certainly using the 40 characters fingerprint but should use the 8 char ID. You've got three options then:

1. You can [configure GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html#index-keyid_002dformat-322) to show the 8 char ID instead of the fingerprint by setting the `keyid-format` option.

   - a) Either explicitly define this option on CLI: `gpg --list-keys --keyid-format short` (Thanks tjheslin1!)
   - b) Or activate this option implicitly through the [options file](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Options.html) (default location is `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`).
2. Try the last 8 digits of your 40 chars fingerprint. This is for the lazy developer ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this! Struggled for a long while but finally made progress with your help. My issue was the key length. Running `gpg2 --list-keys --keyid-format short` was what I needed.

Comment: Thanks @tjheslin1 ! I just added your input :-)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other one is useless.

Comment: It's unforgivable that the Gradle plugin won't handle a full-length key. And to add insult to injury, it uses the *last* 8 chars. Facepalm.

Answer (score 2):

The "secring.gpg" file may not be needed in GPG 2.1 and later versions, and can be generated with commands:
      "gpg --export-secret-keys -o \dir\secring.gpg"